# Hibernate binds temporal Date as Timestamp with native queries

Tags: hibernate, date

I'm upgrading Hibernate in an application from 3.x to the latest (5.4.14 as of now) and working myself through all changes. It appears to have been a change in how *TemporalType.DATE* is used with respect to native queries. To me the change feels like a bug but there is probably a reasonable explanation. As a very simple use case, consider the query below:

```
    final Query query1 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select :date");
    query1.setParameter("date", new Date(), TemporalType.DATE);
    query1.getSingleResult();
```

This is a common setup in this application and the expected behaviour is that the given *Date* will be treated as a *date* in the database. Typically used in range queries against date columns. However, this doesn't work any longer in edges due to the timestamp part of the *Date* being used in the query. When I enable Hibernate tracing, I see the following:

> [BasicBinder#bind(64)] binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Apr 27 11:15:30 CEST 2020]

As a comparison, I did the following query:

```
    final Query query2 = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select :date");
    query2.setParameter("date", LocalDate.now());
    query2.getSingleResult();
```

with the following trace:

> [BasicBinder#bind(64)] binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2020-04-27]

Clearly the two approaches are treated differently. To me, they should be equivalent. When I step into Hibernate code for the *setParameter* call taking a *TemporalType.DATE* I see that Hibernate simply ignores my *TemporalType.DATE*.

This is for native queries, it *does* appear to work as I expect for non-native queries when using *setParameter* and *TemporalType.DATE*.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: @SternK not sure if "dialect" referes to something else, but we use org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean to create the EntityManager which in turn is created with JPA Vendor org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter. Our database is MySQL 5.6

Comment: If you’re using Hibernate 5 or later, pass `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))` as parameter, and your problem should be gone.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks, but it doesn't really answer my question. Why does Hibernate treat a `Date` as `Timestamp`, even though I pass as `TemporalType.DATE`? And only for native queries.